# Can SSRS use Excel from Sharepoint document list as data source?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, reporting-services, datasource, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Question like in title. How can I use Excel in document library on some sharepoint site as data source?

ODBC support local excels. SSRS support sharepoint lists.
But can not find anything about excels in document libraries.